# Powershell sort-by numbers at end of values

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to sort numerically my output with the numbers at the end of each.

`Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ComputerOU,DC=dc,DC=com" -Properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

```
What i would like:
QCL-00010
JPL-00011
TUL-00012
TUL-00013
QCL-00014

What i have:
JPL-00011
QCL-00010
QCL-00014
TUL-00012
TUL-00013
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site works best when you ask a question about a specific issue with some code you’ve already written, rather than a generic “how do I do x”…

Comment: are the names always a uniform length, like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example names, where all numeric values have the same length, padded with leading zeroes, you could simply extend the code you have:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ComputerOU,DC=dc,DC=com" | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | 
    Sort-Object {($_ -split '-')[-1]}
```

However, to be on the safe side I'd cast to `[int]` as well:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ComputerOU,DC=dc,DC=com" | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | 
    Sort-Object {[int]($_ -split '-')[-1]}
```

Result:

```
QCL-00010
JPL-00011
TUL-00012
TUL-00013
QCL-00014
```

<sup>BTW. if all you need is the `.Name` property, do not ask for ALL properties with `-Properties *`</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If every computer in the OU matches the nomenclature, I would just use a calculated property with `Sort-Object` and some pretty standard text munging:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ComputerOU,DC=dc,DC=com" |
Sort-Object -Property @{e={$_.Name.Substring($_.Name.IndexOf('-') + 1)}} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Also, you should avoid `-Properties *` with `Get-AD*` commands unless you absolutely have to. `Name` is returned by default.

Comment: Noted for the -properties *. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do something like this, somewhat depending on how static the format is.

```
$Names = @(
    'JPL-00011'
    'QCL-00010'
    'QCL-00014'
    'TUL-00012'
    'TUL-00013'
)

$Names | Sort-Object {[Void]($_ -match "(\d{5}$)"); $matches[1]}
```

Here I used the matches collection as the sort expression.